# Using decluttering in OpenLayers6 when displaying multiple labels for a line feature

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

**Goal:**

I am trying to display two labels for a line using OpenLayers 6.2 (one above the line, and one below the line) while the decluttering feature is turned on.
Picture of target state with decluttering on.
[image: Make labels closser]

**Problem:**

When decluttering is turned off, I can achieve my goal, but when decluttering is turned on it will turn off the text below the line.

**Background:**

Please refer to the attached CodeSandbox (index.js file) (or the code snippet below) – where I have setup an example of my current javascript–
on line 19 and 30 if the numbers are changed to -23 or 24 (or anything closer to the line) respectively, you will note the bottom label will turn off if decluttering is set to true on line 64
https://codesandbox.io/s/line-label-style-7y5ly

```js
feature.setStyle([
  new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      color: "blue",
      width: 3
    }),
    text: new Text({
      text: "Text 1 Lorem Ipsum",
      placement: "line",
      textBaseline: "middle",
      offsetY: -24,
      padding: [-10, -10, -10, -10],
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: "red" }),
      backgroundStroke: new Stroke({ color: "red" })
    })
  }),
  new Style({
    text: new Text({
      text: "Text 2 Lorem Ipsum",
      placement: "line",
      textBaseline: "middle",
      offsetY: 25,
      padding: [-10, -10, -10, -10],
      stroke: new Stroke({ color: "blue" }),
      backgroundStroke: new Stroke({ color: "blue" })
    })
  })
])
```

Comment: I don't think you can achieve that. If you don't turn off decluttering, when label canvas bounding box intersect only the topmost will be render. I think, this is why one of the labels dissapear when you try to get both close. Under your scenario, you can only play with text size and offsets.

Comment: @cabesuon does that mean there is no way to customise the decluttering function?

Comment: You could use a single text style with the labels separated by newlines https://codesandbox.io/s/line-label-style-kh2r5 but that would limit you to one color and the labels appear left of the center point.

Comment: @nstillwell I honestly don't have that answer, I couldn't find anything like that in the API

Comment: @Mike that is a great alternative, you should post it as an (alternative) answer